# PHP - Manipulating data from csv in a loop

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am working on a project where I need to access a .dat file containing my data in a csv format and then use that to create a products page for an imaginary e-commerce site. I have made it so that I have the correct amount of images/information showing up but cannot manipulate the arrays so that I can present specific pieces of it.

My .dat file looks like this:

```
1001,Logitech G703,Wireless gaming mouse,$99.99,mouse.jpg
1002,Microsoft Keyboard,Bluetooth mechanical keyboard,$59.99,keyboard.jpg
1003,Bose Speaker,Teal wireless surround sound speaker,$159.99,speaker.jpg
1004,KickSTART,Grape flavored Mountain Dew KickSTART,$1.49,kickstart.jpg
1005,Google Pixel,Google's first real smartphone,$799.99,pixel.jpg
1006,Canon EOS REBEL,24.2 Megapixel,$849.00,canon.jpg
1007,Surface Pro 4,128GB 4GB RAM Intel Core i5=>$698.99,surface.jpg
1008,Luna,Siberian Husky Female,$999999.99,luna.jpg
1009,Loki,Siberian Husky Male,$999999.99,loki.jpg
1010,Coffee Mug,"This coffee is making me awesome!",$5.00,mug.jpg
```

And the rest of it looks like this:

```
<?php

$data = file('products.dat');


foreach ($data as $products){        
    $i++;
    $dataExplode = explode(",", $products[$i]);
?>
    <div class="product">
    <image class="product_image" src="img/loki.jpg"> <?php print $products; ?>
    <br>$20.99
    <form method="post" action="viewcart.php?action=add&code=<?php echo 
    $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
    <div><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" /><input 
    type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btnAddAction" /></div>

    </div>
<?php }; ?>
```

When using print on $products within my foreach loop it will display the product information in sequential order like I want but I cannot narrow it down and use the strings that are separated by commas. Furthermore, I need to be able to display the images associated with each product, but have not been able to find a working method for this either.

I appreciate the help and advice!

Comment: Does that 1007 row really have a `=>` instead of a comma before the price? How did that happen?

Comment: `$product_array[$key]["code"]` where are `$product_array` and `$key` defined?  Have you tried using [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)?

Comment: `$dataExplode = explode(",", $products);` (no [$i] there), then use that array: `src="img/<?php echo $dataExplode[4]; ?>">`

Comment: if you do a `var_dump($dataExplode)` you'll see where you find what information.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I was experimenting with my csv file to see if I could somehow turn it into an associative array, but it didn't really work out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify the $i inside the products array, that points to each column without taking lines into account.

You need to explode by lines `\n` and then by comma for each line (product).

When you take a line of products and explode it, it becomes an array.

```
$data= file('products.dat');

foreach ($data as $line){
    $product = explode(",",$line);
    $id = $product[0];
    $title = $product[1];
    $price = $product[2];
    $description = $product[3];
    $image = $product[4];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: well, the beginning with using `file()` was correct. No need to use `file_get_contents` and `explode` there. [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: yeah, but wrong.... the explode needs to be gone... just `$data = file('products.dat');`

Comment: Thank you @Jeff, i didn't know `file()` did the first explode automatically.

Comment: Thanks! This worked out for me. I had done this in a separate more manual way without using the foreach method but it was taking far too long.