# Build formatted HTML/CSS data table from .csv using PHP without SQL?

Tags: php, css, csv, html-table

Have to build custom order report by converting data from an .xls file to a .csv, then formatting resulting data into an HTML table using PHP. Final function/script must format table data this way:

- alphabetically indexed by client name
- calculate sum of total # of orders
- calculated average cost of orders using the total sum of all orders
- orders with balances due to be formatted in color

  ```
  <?php echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
  $f = fopen("orders.csv", "r");
  while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($line as $cell) {
          echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>\n";
  }
  fclose($f);
  echo "\n</table></body>";
  ```

Here is the code I used to get an HTML table with the data on it, but I can't do anything to output it properly with the desired format. Any suggestions to get the results necessary? Thanks...

Comment: "I can't do anything to output it properly with the desired format"  Have you _tried_ anything to achieve those items?

Comment: Parse the data, store it in an array, do the calculations and sorting that you need, then print it out to html.

Comment: Read each line, one a time.  With each line, explode() on the ','.  With the exploded line, now in an array, do another foreach to output each value inside TD cells.  Also read up on HTML pages, you have to give header and  title at a minimum (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp).

Comment: Similar question, similar answer!  Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838248/php-manipulating-data-from-csv-in-a-loop

Comment: thanks for all responses. Patrick Q, no need to be rude; my question exists because, YES, I HAVE been trying to get the 'desired results' for a week now, and asking here was my last resort. I kindly asked for a knudge or two in the right direction, not for your belittlement or incredulous sarcasm. I also see you responded to the linked query posted by another help seeker in a similarly dismissive fashion. If you have nothing positive to contribute, log out and go do something else. I taught myself HTML, CSS, some JS, and am beginning PHP. Thanks again to those w sincere attempts to help.